# Boas 17.28 - simplify a complex expression

Tags: complex-numbers

This is a question from "Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences" (Boas, 3rd Ed), Question 17.28: 
Express the following expression in terms of a hyperbolic function:
$$ \left|\frac{(a+bi)^2e^b-(a-bi)^2e^{-b}}{4abie^{-ia}}\right|^2$$
Here is my attempt: by using the fact that $|z|^2=zz^*:$
\begin{gather}
\left|\frac{(a+bi)^2e^b-(a-bi)^2e^{-b}}{4abie^{-ia}}\right|^2=\frac{(a+bi)^2e^b-(a-bi)^2e^{-b}}{4abie^{-ia}}\frac{(a-bi)^2e^b-(a+bi)^2e^{-b}}{-4abie^{ia}} \\
=\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2[e^{2b}+e^{-2b}]-(a-bi)^4-(a+bi)^4}{16a^2b^2} \\
=\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2[2\cosh (2b)]-(2a^4-12a^2b^2+2b^4)}{16a^2b^2} \implies \text{can't proceed!}
\end{gather}
The answer given in the book is:
$$1+(a^2+b^2)^2(2ab)^{-2}\sinh^2 b$$
Can someone give me some ideas on how to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: $\cosh (2b) = \cosh^2 b + \sinh^2 b = 1 + 2 \sinh^2 b$ should take you farther.

Comment: Daniel Fischer's comment is appropo. And maybe multiply out the $(a^{2}+b^{2})^{2}$?

Comment: Daniel Fischer is right. I forgot this formula. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2[2\cosh (2b)]-(2a^4-12a^2b^2+2b^4)}{16a^2b^2} \\
= 1+\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2[2\cosh (2b)]-(2a^4+4a^2b^2+2b^4)}{16a^2b^2}\\
=1+\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2[2\cosh (2b)]-2(a^2+b^2)^2}{16a^2b^2}\\
=1+\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2[2\cosh (2b)-2]}{16a^2b^2}$

$2\cosh(2b)-2\\
=e^{2b}+e^{-2b}-2\\
=4\sinh(b)^2
$

$1+\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2[2\cosh (2b)-2]}{16a^2b^2}\\
=1+\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2*4\sinh(b)^2}{16a^2b^2}\\
=1+(a^2+b^2)^2(2ab)^{-2}\sinh(b)^2$

Comment: Thanks, but I think following Fischer and Keister's comments should be more straight forward: $\cdots = \frac{2a^4+4a^2b^2+2b^4+(4a^4+8a^2b^2+4b^4)\sinh^2 b-2a^4+12a^2b^2-2b^4}{16a^2b^2}$

Comment: Yep. I didn't use any formulas. I use the defination of sinh and cosh.